# Prove that a continuous and $\mathcal{F}_t$ adapted process is progressively measurable

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, stochastic-processes, measurable-functions

I would like to show that if $X_t$ is a continuous and adapted stochastic process (real valued) then it is progressively measurable.

Here is my attempt : consider $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Then we have

$$
X^{-1}(B) =\big\{ (\omega,t)\in\Omega\times [0,T] : X(\omega,t)\in B\big\} = \big\{ \omega\in\Omega : X(\omega,.)\in B\big\}\times[0,T]\cap\Omega\times \big\{ t\in[0,T] : X(.,t)\in B\big\}\in\mathcal{F}_t\otimes\mathcal{B}([0,T])
$$

Using the fact that $X$ is continuous in $t$ (at fixed $\omega$ and hence measurable from $([0,T],\mathcal{B}([0,T])$ to $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ the set $\big\{ t\in[0,T] : X(.,t)\in B\big\}$ is in $\mathcal{B}([0,T])$.

A similar argument when $t$ is fixed shows that the set $\big\{ \omega\in\Omega : X(\omega,.)\in B\big\}$ is in $\mathcal{F}_t$ since $X_t$ is adapted.

That was my idea. I would like to know if it is correct please and if not what can I improve ?

Comment: Please reread and elaborate on the sentence after the equation.  It seems to have some typos and I am not sure that it really expresses a coherent strategy.  It certainly doesn't seem to be a complete proof at this point.

Comment: @NateEldredge Very sorry for the missing part of the sentence. I have added the missing sentences and hope that my strategy is clearer. Let me know if it is still not the case please.

Comment: The argument you provided is not so much true or false as it is not well defined. The standard way to show the claim is to approximate (ex. using dyadic intervals) the process, so that the process is a pointwise limit of progressively measurable processes.

Comment: @VasilyMelnikov Thank you for your comment. I think now I see what is not well defined, it is the notation $X(.,\omega)$ ? Indeed when rereading this I saw that the set involving $ X(.,\omega)$ is unclear since one of the two variables is not explicitly mentionned. In fact I wanted to work on the function of one variable by fixing the other variable, I did not succed. Concerning your method, I never thought of this approach, it requires more work  since we need to prove that the limit of a progressively measurable function is also progressively measurable.I will try something in that direction